# Resizing pages in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, editing, adobe-acrobat

I am using Acrobat Professional 8 to assemble a document from two imported page images (JPGs). Acrobat seems to interpret the images at screen resolution, and creates a document that's about 35" by 46" instead of 8.5" x 11". How can I scale down the page size within Acrobat?

Comment: How are you generating the PDF in the first place?

Comment: Try Evermap Autopagex plug-in.

Comment: Print it as 8.5x11 and have Adobe Acrobat PDF printer engine sample it down for you.

Answer (score 6):

A few options, in roughly increasing order of difficulty:

1. The easiest way I can think of would be to print it to the Adobe PDF (Distiller) driver with "Shrink to Fit" turned on.
2. Copy and paste the images into a blank 8.5x11 PDF file and then use the TouchUp Object tool to scale it down.
3. If your version of Acrobat has the Print Production tools, go into the cropping tool and change the various boxes to be 8.5x11 (multiply by 72 if you need to give the dimensions in points) and then use the TouchUp Object tool to scale the image.

(These are all possible in Adobe Acrobat Professional 9, which is what I have.  I think all three should be available in version 8, but I'm not completely sure.)

Answer (score 2):

Within Acrobat Professional, do this:

1. go to tools/crop
2. make a crop mark were ever on the page
3. hit return
4. This will prompt you to verify the size, if its correct hit OK. I like to do it more accurately then drawn, so I remove the margin controls and choose "change page size". Make it whatever size then center it.

It most cases I use this when I want to replicate the trim from the printer.

Answer (score 2):

Format page size A5 in Adobe Acrobat X: Start - Control Panel - Printer & faxes - Adobe PDF (Distiller) - Preferences - Adobe PDF Settings - Paper Name = A5 (type with blank after A5) - when Add/Modify.

Comment: I think the OP wants to do this after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

Printing to a new size destroys layers. If you want everything intact, use the Print Production, Preflight, Gear icon, Pages, Scale pages to specified size, enter long and short sides in millimeters. It also has presets for A4 and to only scale page content rather than the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click ‘Print’
2. Set printer to ‘Adobe PDF’
3. In ‘Page Sizing & Handling’ > Disable ‘Choose paper source from PDF page size’
4. Click ‘Properties’ at the top next to ‘Printer’
5. Go to ‘Layout’ tab > Click ‘advanced’
6. In ‘Paper size’ choose ‘Postscript Custom Page Size’ and edit page size as needed.
7. ‘OK’ everything and back in original ‘Print’ menu click ‘Fit’ under ‘Page sizing & handling’
8. ‘Print’ to PDF

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF isn't protected, you could try printing the PDF into another PDF of the page size you want.  If Acrobat won't print to the Acrobat printer (like it is protected), I've use third party PDF tools (free ones) for Acrobat to print to and it worked fine.

Alternately, you could print the images into the page size you want and resolution you want, then combine the PDFs together.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro v10.1.4.  Had a request to insert jpgs into a pdf file so that they were full page in the pdf.  Some of the jpgs were quite small.  Opened the jpg, choose Print - select Full Page - deselect fit to frame - print to Adobe pdf file.  Go to Acrobat, create pdf from file(s), select (all) the pdf files created from the jpg(s) - Open - Save

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to do this is to export the .pdf to another program such as PowerPoint or Word and resave the resultant .pptx or .docx file as a .pdf. This took my 7.5 x 10 .pdf to an 8.5 x 11 in pretty much 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

A good to crop or resize PDF pages:

http://www.nitropdf.com/help/resize_crop_pdf_pages.htm

Hope this will help!

Comment: This discusses a third-party commercial product. My question is about Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: I know but I did not see it so I thought proposing you a Third-Party apps could be usefull if you need to resize asap. Sorry about that.