# How to control DPI/PPI (or page size) when converting images to PDF with Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, images, adobe-acrobat

I am on Windows 10 running Adobe Acrobat XI Pro. I have a bunch of PNG images with a resolution 2472 x 4119 pixels which I want to convert into a single PDF, one image per page. From Windows Explorer I can select the images, right-click and choose "Convert to Adobe PDF". Or from Adobe Acrobat, I can go to "File" > "Create" > "Combine files into a single PDF".

Either way, same result, which is perfect except for one major problem. The resulting page size is 34.33 x 57.21 inches, because the images are set at 72x72 DPI by default. This wouldn't even bother me except that Acrobat will not OCR pages larger than 40 in. **Surely, there must be a way to change this default setting of 72 DPI to something more sane, in this case 300 DPI?**

The only viable work around I've found so far is to use the Linux utility `img2pdf`. If I run `img2pdf -s 300dpi --output out.pdf *.png` problem solved. But surely there is a way to accomplish the same thing in Adobe Acrobat?

My question is quite similar to "[Resizing pages in Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/111056/resizing-pages-in-adobe-acrobat-pro)", but I am trying to get to the root of the issue instead of fixing it after the fact. Re-printing or processing the PDF as suggested there causes quality/resolution/compression issues. I just want to know whether and how Acrobat can just get it right the first time. **If there is no possible way to tell Acrobat what DPI to use by default, that would be a definitive answer, but I just find it hard to believe that such a sophisticated program lacks such a basic feature.**

I've tried to get an answer to this [on the Adobe support forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-control-ppi-when-making-pdf-pages-from-scanned-images/m-p/11366016?page=1) and it's been absolutely maddening, as people are giving me all kinds of totally irrelevant suggestions as if my question is impossible to understand and I'm not sure why.

EDIT: Distiller has DPI settings, but these don't seem to have any relation to the "Combine files into a single PDF" function. If there is a simple way to use Distiller on a batch of images, that might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set what DPI to use during the converting process in Acrobat. The only method not to adjust the Page Size manually afterward is to create or change pixel per meter values of the PNG files. You can do it by Exiftool.

```
exiftool a.png -pixelsperunitx=11811 -pixelsperunity=11811
```

Comment: Haven't rested this for myself but makes sense, thank you! (I gave up long ago and have been happily using img2pdf instead of Adobe.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about img2pdf!